# How do I create a non content editable div inside a content editable iframe?

Tags: javascript

I need to make a some parts inside an contenteditable iframe as non-editable. How do I do that?
The below code works in chrome but not in firefox. Everything is editable in firefox. Ineed the checkbox to be noneditable

```
<iframe contentEditable="true" >
    Editable text<div contentEditable="false"><input type="checkbox" /></div>
</iframe>
```

Comment: This may be helpful https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Content_Editable

Answer (score 9):

Use this:

```
Editable text<div contentEditable="false" readonly>Non content editable text</div>
```

If you want to use JQuery:

```
$('#divId').attr('readonly', 'true');
```

Comment: Accord to XHTML standard, you have to assign to the readonly attribute, also a value. With this edit, the Sankalp Mishra's answer become: `Editable text<div contenteditable="false" readonly="readonly">Non content editable text</div>`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with an input text with an attribut readonly.
I found the width of the input with a span invisible and I got the width of the span outside of my contenteditable.

Works like a cham !