# Using form elements - checkboxes - inside contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html

I need to place form elements (simple checkboxes) inside a `contenteditable` `<div />`. It's important that checkboxes are not not for show - user needs to be able to click on them, turning them on or off. Unfortunately, they don't work while `contenteditable` is set - it's not possible to click on them nor their labels, at least in Firefox.

[Here's a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/y71nt25u/)

```js
$('#enable-edit').change (function() {
  $('div').attr('contenteditable', $(this).prop ('checked') ? 'true' : 'false');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true">
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="fail" /><label for="fail">You cannot click on me (nor edit this text) if contenteditable is true</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    ...but you can edit this text
  </p>
</div>

<input type="checkbox" id="enable-edit" checked /><label for="enable-edit">Enable contenteditable</label>
```

Is there anything that can be done to remedy that without handling the click event manually via JavaScript? And if there isn't, will handling the click events on those checkboxes be an acceptable cross-browser solution?

Comment: Why does it have to be semantically inside the `contenteditable` div? Can't you leave it outside the editable container and use css to manipulate the layout to make it appear as if it is "inside"?

Comment: @Daniel_L it appears to be excessively complicated to implement, especially considering how `contenteditable` makes the content *editable* (i.e. moving around unpredictably).

Comment: @Septagram anything inside the contenteditable area can be deleted. IMO it makes little sense to place elements that contribute to your business logic inside a contenteditable. Moving the checkboxes outside the div and styling it to appear as one form group would mitigate all your problems.

Comment: @Daniel_L okay, long story: We need an editable rich edit box that allows lists of checkboxes (like Evernote). Checkboxes are not business logic, they are whatever user wants them to be. They may be added, removed and checked/unchecked arbitrarily.

Comment: With Safari 10.1.1 on MacOS 10.12.5 I can click the first box whether or not contenteditable is selected using the second. Likewise with Chrome 58.0.3029.110 and Opera 45.0.2552.898.  However, I do see the problem as reported using Firefox 54.0 on the same machine, and on IE 11.0.9600.18697 on Windows 7 Pro under VMware Fusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14556056/1022914), you can create a non-editable DIV or SPAN inside an editable DIV. Simply wrap your checkbox in a SPAN and you will have a clickable checkbox.

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">
  <span contenteditable="false"><input type="checkbox" id="fail" /></span>And you can still edit this text
</div>
```

Unfortunately, on Firefox you cannot delete a non-editable SPAN by using <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, though you can still delete it by first selecting with mouse.

*(tested in Chrome and Firefox on both desktop and mobile, as well as in Android Stock and IE11)*

Comment: Why did you add the "feature" to prevent changing checkbox? The point of the original question was to allow the user checking/unchecking it :\

Comment: I've edited your answer so it would answer the original question. Hope it's okay.

Comment: Ah, I misread your question. I was using Chrome where you can toggle the checkbox so I thought you wanted it to prevent that.