# CKeditor - Is there any way to use live checkboxes inside the editor?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

While CKEditor supports *creation* of HTML forms including the use of checkboxes, my needs are slightly different.

I would like users to be able to check and uncheck checkboxes while creating their content. Essentially we use a custom template system, the template loads in CKEditor and the user fills out required details and appends their own content (text/images/etc.). Ideally we would be able to create templates with yes/no questions and the users would check the requisite checkbox when consuming a template.

I know this isn't natively supported, but is there an alternative or workaround to enable checkboxes/toggles via CKEditor? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37106151/using-form-elements-checkboxes-inside-contenteditable-div

Answer (score 0):

There is a possible way you can achieve this. For example, you have the below input box inside the editor.

```
<input class="myplugin" type="checkbox">
```

You can access this `checkbox` when it's clicked using the below code.

```
editor.on('contentDom',function(){
   var html = $(editor.editable().$);
   $('.myplugin',html).on('click',function(){
       //this will return the input element 
       console.log(this);
       //check it's checked or not
       if($(this).attr('checked') == 'true'){
          // Add/Remove class or something
       }else{
          // Add/Remove class or something
       }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

yes this can be done, you will need to user source mode to add this and it will require some additional jquery function as per need.

Exact code can be provided - but we need to know what exactly you want to do like just on and off?

Here is also a good example - jsfiddle.net/y71nt25u/  if you have something predefined you can pre-define in code and later can use in editor.

Comment: As mentioned, You will have to use in 2 parts. one  js part in your page and html part in editor and this will work perfectly fine.

Comment: Please update your jsfiddle using CKEditor. This isn't as simple a task as you seem to be suggesting.

Comment: Yes i know, its not that simple but doable :) If you have jsfiddle using CKEditor, Please share and i will update code there.

Comment: Sorry, I only just saw this. JSFiddle is here: jsfiddle.net/s58pa6nu @Harish